# attribute added to MessageContext in request don't show up in exception chain

Tags: rest, jax-rs, apache-wink

I have a custom `RequestHandler` where I do some logic, and then add an attribute to the `MessageContext` so that I can retrieve it in all my `Resource`s (via the @Context annotation). This works great. On the response, I need to access this same attribute. I am able to retrieve it if my `Resource` method returns successfully, but not if an exception is thrown. Is it possible to get this same attributes on the `MessageContext` somehow, even when an exception is thrown? I use a custom `ExceptionMapper`, so I need to throw an exception if it doesn't complete properly.